# Is there a list of altcoin communities that has the most active developers?

Tags: altcoin, community

In terms of updating the codebase, bug response, new features etc.

Who are the front runners that at least update at least once or twice a month?

If an altcoin that doesn't even update their codebase or bug responses within a month should not qualify.

Answer (score 2):

Coin Gecko (https://www.coingecko.com/en) has all sorts of metrics on what coins have active communities/developers. I'm not sure how exactly they measure each of these things, but it may be what you're looking for.

Comment: It appears to be by the frequency of commits. Seems like it could be gamed with a cron script.

Comment: // , Yeah, maybe it unintentionally measures the developers who are best at gaming rating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Test this one:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=550165.0 List of all related forums / chats / boards to Bitcoin & Alt-coins & E-money

See, there is a poll, where you can get an activity of users of bitcointalk on side places:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=738375 What forums, chats, boards do you use？